# How can I determine if a string is a correctly formatted path regardless of whether it actually exists?

Tags: string, powershell, path

I am creating a function and I want to validate that a string passed in to my function is a correctly formatted path. Test-Path determines if the path exists, which I don't want. Is there a RegEx expression that can do this? Or some other native Cmdlet?

Thanks.

Comment: RegEx possible answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/51504254

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `Test-Path -IsValid` to check for valid but non-existent paths:

```
Test-Path -LiteralPath 'C:\Whatever' -IsValid
```

The catch though, is that "valid" doesn't seem to mean the same thing as "correctly formatted".

For example, if I use `D:\Whatever` it's also valid on my machine, while `E:\Whatever` is not; because there is no such PSDrive (but `C` and `D` exist).

Also strange, `WSman:\whatever` is `False` while `HKCU:\whatever` is `True`.

It does seem to think UNC paths are valid.

If you're going to look at trying to validate a path another way, you could start with the set of invalid characters, which you can get with `[System.IO.Path]::InvalidPathChars`.

But here's something weird too, one of those characters is `§`, and yet `C:\§whatever` returns `True` from `Test-Path -IsValid`.

I'm probably raising more questions than answers here.

---

From comments:

> I'm looking to validate a fully qualified path with drive letter and possible directories. "C:\SomeDirectory\ or D:\blah\blah"

I think the most straightforward thing to do here may be to first check if the path "is rooted", and then to cast it as a `[DirectoryInfo]` object:

```
if ([System.IO.Path]::IsPathRooted($path)) {
    # this will throw an exception if the path can't be used
    # for example Z:\whatever is accepted, ZZ:\whatever is not
    $validatedPath = ([System.IO.DirectoryInfo]$path).FullName
}
else {
    throw [System.ArgumentException]"Only fully-qualified paths are accepted."
}
```

You could also choose to keep the `[DirectoryInfo]` object rather than "converting" it back to a string with `.FullName`, as that object has a number of useful properties and methods, even if the directory doesn't exist.

```
$path = 'Z:\whatever' -as [System.IO.DirectoryInfo]

$path | Format-List *
$path | Get-Member
```

Comment: Already tried that. Not what I'm after. See this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47505716/why-does-powershell-test-path-isvalid-always-returns-true

I could pass it "flgkdahlkadgfh" and it would still return true.

Comment: As pointed out in that accepted answer, `flgkdahlkadgfh` is a valid path though. So what exactly are you looking for?

Comment: I'm looking to validate a fully qualified path with drive letter and possible directories. "C:\SomeDirectory\ or D:\blah\blah"

Comment: Ok that's something! I've edited to show a possible solution.

Comment: Thanks much for the example of IsPathRooted. Oddly though "D:sdgsdfshdfh" is still accepted as a valid path. I would think that the backslash should be required.

Comment: Ah, it isn't required because that's a valid way of specifying a path relative to your current path but on a different drive. If I'm in `C:\Users\briantist` at the command prompt (not in powershell though), I can do `dir D:desktop` to try to get a directory listing of `D:\Users\briantist\desktop`. This is actually the difference between being "rooted" and being "absolute"; the path `\Users\briantist` is absolute, even though it's not rooted (to a drive).

Comment: Got it. I think my validation function is more than sufficient at this point. Thanks for all your help.